# Converting latitude/longitude to decimal degrees for entire data frame

Tags: python, data-science, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to convert columns of latitude and longitude and create a new column for decimal degrees.

Both code examples work great for a single coordinate (also from Stack Overflow), but I need to iterate over multiple columns.

```
latitude = "20-18-6.65N"
N = 'N' in latitude
d, m, s = map(float, latitude[:-1].split('-'))
latitude = (d + m / 60. + s / 3600.) * (1 if N else -1)
longitude = "40-17-12.13W"
W = 'W' in longitude
d, m, s = map(float, longitude[:-1].split('-'))
longitude = (d + m / 60. + s / 3600.) * (-1 if W else 1)

print(latitude)
print(longitude)


latitude = ("20-18-6.65N")
longitude = ("40-17-12.13W")

latitude = sum(float(x) / 60 ** n for n, x in enumerate(latitude[:-1].split('-')))  * (1 if 'N' in     latitude[-1] else -1)
longitude = sum(float(x) / 60 ** n for n, x in enumerate(longitude[:-1].split('-'))) * (1 if 'E' in longitude[-1] else -1)

print(latitude, longitude)


latlong = df.iloc[:, 0:3] # Subset for columns needed.
latlong_df = pd.DataFrame(data = latlong) # transform into pandas df.
lats_df = latlong_df.iloc[:, 1] # subset for latitude column.
longs_df = latlong_df.iloc[:, 2] # subset for longitude column.
for i in latlong_df: 
    lats_df = sum(float(x) / 60 ** n for n, x in enumerate(lats_df[:-1].split('-')))  * (1 if 'N' in lats_df[-1] else -1)
    longs_df = sum(float(x) / 60 ** n for n, x in enumerate(longs_df[:-1].split('-'))) * (1 if 'E' in longs_df[-1] else -1)
    print(lats_df, longs_df)
```

The last code block results in this error message: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

I've tried using a for loop, but I get this error message: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'. I've also tried using other data types other than a data frame and get the same error message. Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show the actual code that produced these errors, and which version produced which error.

Comment: Is there a reason why not using a library as [LatLon23](https://pypi.org/project/LatLon23/)?

Comment: You can convert your conversion code into a function then apply it to give new converted columns from one or more DF columns. You need to use Pandas functions such as map() and apply(). You have posted only your conversion code; what you need to do is post a sample of your DataFrame and the results you want.